# How to create running conditional sum variables by class and ID in SAS

Tags: sas

From a cumulative episode count (if time intervals are less than 10 days, it is considered one episode), I want to calculate a “wide” and “long” version of running episode count based on class by ID.

This is what my data looks like right now.

```
id  Class   Date      Obsvn Episode_Sum
9   Wide    3/10/2012   1   1
9   Wide    3/12/2012   2   1
9   Wide    7/1/2012    111 2
9   Wide    7/3/2012    2   2
108 Wide    3/31/2011   1   1
108 Long    3/31/2011   1   1
108 Wide    4/17/2011   17  2
108 Wide    6/24/2011   68  3
108 Wide    6/16/2012   358 4
108 Wide    7/20/2012   34  5
108 Wide    7/27/2012   7   5
```

I achieved the running count by this code:

```
data want (drop=lag); set have;

by id date;

format lag mmddyy10.;
lag=lag(date);

if first.id then obsvn=1;
else obsvn=max(intck("Day", Lag, date),1);

if first.id then episode_sum=1;
else if obsvn>10 then episode_sum+1;

run;
```

I want my data to look like this:

```
id  Class   Date     Obsvn Sum Wide Long
9   Wide    3/10/2012   1   1   1   0
9   Wide    3/12/2012   2   1   1   0
9   Wide    7/1/2012    111 2   2   0
9   Wide    7/3/2012    2   2   2   0
108 Wide    3/31/2011   1   1   1   0
108 Long    3/31/2011   1   1   1   1
108 Wide    4/17/2011   17  2   2   1
108 Wide    6/24/2011   68  3   3   1
108 Wide    6/16/2012   358 4   4   1
108 Wide    7/20/2012   34  5   5   1
108 Wide    7/27/2012   7   5   5   1
```

But I am getting this:

```
id  Class   Date    Obsvn  Sum Wide Long
9   Wide    3/10/2012   1   1   1   0
9   Wide    3/12/2012   2   1   1   0
9   Wide    7/1/2012    111 2   2   0
9   Wide    7/3/2012    2   2   **1**   0
108 Wide    3/31/2011   1   1   1   **1**
108 Long    3/31/2011   1   1   1   1
108 Wide    4/17/2011   17  2   2   1
108 Wide    6/24/2011   68  3   3   1
108 Wide    6/16/2012   358 4   4   1
108 Wide    7/20/2012   34  5   5   1
108 Wide    7/27/2012   7   5   **1**   1
```

This is my code to create the episodes by wide and long. I am trying to account for when each ID switches class. How do I achieve this?

```
/*Calculating Long*/

if (first.id and class in ("Long")) then Episode_Long=1;
else if obsvn>10 and class in ("Long") then Episode_Long+1;
retain Episode_Long;

if (obsvn<10 and class in ("Long")) then Episode_Long=1;

if class not in ("Long") then do;
if first.id and class not in ("Long") then Episode_Long=0;
retain Episode_Long;
end;

/*Calculating Wide */

if (obsvn<10 and class in ("Wide")) then Episode_Wide=1   ;  
if (first.id and class in ("Wide")) then Episode_Wide=1;
else if obsvn>10 and class in ("Wide") then Episode_Wide+1;
retain Episode_Wide;
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to treat ID and CLASS as the grouping variable?  Did you try sorting and using both variables in the BY statement and your FIRST. logic?

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for your reply. I am sorting by ID and DATE. I am not able to add the CLASS variable to the BY statement because the running total is dependent on when the episode occurs. Many times a record may start on wide, then switches to long over time. I need to account for the switching while producing the correct number episodes based on the days between dates. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Jasamack, have you tried using a retain statement? this would allow you to keep state of your variable during PDV execution...

Comment: @DanielVieira, Hello, yes, I have tried the retain statement, which is in my example code above, but I am unsure of its correct placement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part is that you have two records for the same DATE in the second ID group. So you want to keep track of that when calculating the change in days.

Here is one way.  First let's enter your source data (and desired results).

```
data have ;
  input id Class $ Date :mmddyy. EObsvn ESum EWide ELong ;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
9   Wide    3/10/2012   1   1   1   0
9   Wide    3/12/2012   2   1   1   0
9   Wide    7/1/2012    111 2   2   0
9   Wide    7/3/2012    2   2   2   0
108 Wide    3/31/2011   1   1   1   0
108 Long    3/31/2011   1   1   1   1
108 Wide    4/17/2011   17  2   2   1
108 Wide    6/24/2011   68  3   3   1
108 Wide    6/16/2012   358 4   4   1
108 Wide    7/20/2012   34  5   5   1
108 Wide    7/27/2012   7   5   5   1
;
```

You might want to find the dates where WIDE or LONG gaps exist first.

```
data long ;
  set have ;
  by id date;
  where class='Long';
  if first.date;
  lag=lag(date);

  if first.id then call missing(lag,obsvn);
  else obsvn=max(intck("Day", Lag, date),1);
  lflag = missing(lag) or obsvn > 10 ;
  keep id date lflag ;

run;


data wide ;
  set have ;
  by id date;
  where class='Wide';
  if first.date;
  lag=lag(date);

  if first.id then call missing(lag,obsvn);
  else obsvn=max(intck("Day", Lag, date),1);
  wflag = missing(lag) or obsvn > 10 ;
  keep id date wflag ;

run;
```

Then merge it back onto the source by date and calculate your counters.

```
data want ;
  merge have wide long ;
  by id date;

  if first.date then do ;
    lag=lag(date);
    format lag yymmdd10.;
    if first.id then call missing(lag,obsvn);
    else obsvn=max(intck("Day", Lag, date),1);
    retain lag obsvn;
  end;

  if first.id then call missing(sum,wide,long);
  if missing(lag) or obsvn > 10 then sum+first.date ;
  wide + (wflag and first.date);
  long + (lflag and first.date);

run;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you! It appears that this code gets me closer to my goal, but it doesn't work well when the switch (long to wide or vice versa) occurs in the middle of the episode timeline. If there is a string of "long" observations then a "wide" observation occurs for one particular record, the wide variable stays 0 when it should be counting the occurrence.

Comment: Sounds like you might need two separate "lag" variables.  One for WIDE and one for LONG.

Comment: I updated it to process the LONG and WIDE in separate steps. Try it now with your messier data.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work for all of the various classes across IDs. I just added: `If obsvn=. then obsvn=1;` to the end of the code.